# Anylogic, seize resource from pool based on certain conditions

Tags: process, resources, anylogic, discrete

Question has been asked and answered before, see [Anylogic - dynamic specification of resources to seize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533181/anylogic-dynamic-specification-of-resources-to-seize).  But the multiple trolls on stackoverflow requested me to ask same question again, regardless.. - as asking it there is seen as an "answer" and not a "question".

Anylogic 8.7.2.
I create a Resource Pool `myworkers`.
Of agent type `workers`.
Open the `workers` agent and add a variable `offloadBay` (or parameter, does not matter), `INT, default value 0`.
In main I use a `seize` block to seize 4 resources from this pool, but they need to meet the condition `offloadBay == 0`.
In the seize block I select `Customise resource choice == true ; Recource choice condition = (unit.offloadBay == 0)`.
On running the project, I get the error - "*offloadBay cannot be resolved or is not a field*".

It seems reference to the keyword `unit` does not actually reference the resource unit - none of the `unit's` parameters, variables, functions, etc. are available to be called when referencing `unit.`

Please advice on what am I doing wrong?  Alternatively, how do I select a resource from the ResourcePool based on a certain condition or property of the resource? (*demo project can be provided on request, please advice where to send to*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enforcing the resource type. This happens because you are in the seize block and when you use "unit" you may be referring to different resource agent types. Not all of them may have the "offloadBay" variable. So, use:

((Worker)unit).offloadBay == 0

Comment: Emile, that does not work.  Anylogic now responds with two errors: `offloadBay cannot be resolved or is not a field` and `Incompatible operand type Workers and int`

Comment: The error "Incompatible operand type Workers and int" appears when the two sides of  "==" are of a different type. This is telling you that the 0 is of type int and whatever is on the other side is of type Workers. Can you copy and paste what exactly you wrote in the Resource choice condition?

Comment: I think you wrote "Workers" instead of "Worker".

Comment: hang on a moment please - you are a bit fast on me... the speed of your response is much appreciated though!! I had `(Workers)unit.offloadBay` - seems there is set of extra brackets required?  testing at moment

Comment: That is it yes!!  Needs the extra brackets `((Workers)unit).offloadBay`  - tested it multiple levels, works perfectly!!  Thank you Emile, you're a star!!